# How to force a Documentation <see /> element to reference the type instead of the property with the same name?

Tags: c#, .net, xml-documentation

It is relatively common practice for property names to default to the type name when the type name is significant enough;

```cs
public class User { }
public class UserSession
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a <see cref="UserSession" /> instance
    /// with the given <see cref="User" />
    /// </summary>
    public UserSession(User user)
    {
        User = user;
    }

    public User User { get; private set; }
}
```

My problem is that the `<see cref="User" />` element in the XML documentation refers to the `UserSession.User` property. What should I write in order to reference the `User` type instead?

Comment: Have you tried the fully qualified namespace?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the full name of the type, including the namespace.

Answer (score 3):

Write the full name of User as shown in [`<see>` (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acd0tfbe.aspx) with `System.Console.WriteLine(String)`:

```
<see cref="YourNamespace.User"/>
```